# CosmosDb Count query consuming excessive RUs

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What is the best way to optimise the following CosmosDb Query:

```sql
SELECT count(1)
FROM c
where c.creationDateTs > c.dueDateTs
AND c.partitionKey="DocReadTests_assignments"
```

At the moment is giving us a cost of 38210.17RUs on a container with just over 1 million records.

We have the standard oob container index policy (all fields are indexed) and also tried creating composite index on (creationDateTs ASC, dueDateTs ASC) and there was no change in consumption.

Comment: What is `creationDateTs`: Numeric? String? That is the likely issue, if you're doing string comparisons (maybe try storing an additional property with a numeric date for comparison purposes, like unix clock ticks or something?). What happens if you remove that from your query - does the RU cost go down?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both creationDateTs and dueDateTs are already numbers in this case (they are unix timestamps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where c.creationDateTs > c.dueDateTs
```

Is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

The best that can be done is a seek on `partitionKey` and the remainder cannot be converted to a straight forward index seek and requires the pair of values from all documents in the logical partition to be retrieved and compared.

In theory this could be done by scanning all the entries in the composite index rather than retrieving the full documents but this is still less efficient than a seek - and sounds like this might not be implemented if you didn't see any change in RU after creating such an index.

Maybe you could also try a composite index of `partitionKey ASC, creationDateTs ASC, dueDateTs ASC)` to see if that fares any better (in allowing the exact index entries that match the logical partition key and so need to be scanned to be found).

If you add a new property to the document of DueDateCreationDateDiff that is just `dueDateTs - creationDateTs` (or based on [DateTimeDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/datetimediff) depending on what format those properties are in) then you can do a straightforward index seek on

```
where c.DueDateCreationDateDiff  < 0
AND c.partitionKey="DocReadTests_assignments"
```

Potentially the `DueDateCreationDateDiff` could be a [computed property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/computed-properties?tabs=dotnet) but this is still preview functionality at the moment so you may prefer to maintain it manually for now.

Comment: Hi @martin. Thanks for the reply. I did try with the `(partitionKey ASC, creationDateTs ASC, dueDateTs ASC)` but no luck, the RUs were about the same. But I do like your other suggestion about creating an extra property with the timeDiff value. I haven't had a chance to try it specifically yet (need to find a way to update over 1 million documents :) ) but I tried with `c.creationDateTs > xxxx` (which used the same principle) and got 11.6RUs which is great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hugo also worth mentioning that you could look at using the analytical store for this sort of query as then there is no need to add helper properties to documents in the transactional store. But there are restrictions with analytical store (e.g. not compatible with continuous backup) and might not be worth it if this is the only query you have that you would use it for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Martin. We did look into Synapse Link and it would have been perfect for us (we are building an entire dashboard on top of our CosmosDb) but then we discovered that we cannot have continuous backup at the same time which was a killer for us.